# Explanation of Output of Bitwise operations

Tags: c

```
void main() 
{ 
int x=7; 
printf("%d",x&(x-1));
int y=6; 
printf("%d",y&(y-1)); 
printf("%d",y>>2); 


}
```

When I put an odd number I get output n-1 where n is a odd number but when i put y= even number I get output 0.I am not able to understand this please help.

My second question is that when i print y>>2 that is 6>>2 I get ouput 1.Please explain me this also. I know these are bitwise operations but my concept is not clear.Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C - grab a paper and a pen(cil) and work it out.

Comment: Also, `(x & (x-1)) == 0` can be used to checks if `x` is a power of 2 (or 0)

Answer (score 0):

Let's break each line up:

```
x&(x-1) => 0x111 & 0x110 => 0x110 => 6
```

... and:

```
y&(y-1)) => ox110 & 0x101 => 0x100 => 4
```

... and finally:

```
y>>2 => 0x110 >> 2 => 0x001 => 1
```

**Remark:** It's probably a good idea to review your knowledge of [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operations are exactly that.  you take your number and you `and` each bit with the other number.

What that means, is if both numbers have a `1` at the slot, than you output `1`, else, you output `0`

so, for your example of `7` you have

```
0111
0110
```

result:

```
0110 (6)
```

for your example of `6` you have

```
0110
0101
```

result:

```
0100 (4)
```

---

right shift (`>>`) just shifts all the bits to the right, so if you take 6

```
0110
```

and shift all the bits to the right twice, you end up with

```
0001
```

or `1`

Answer (score 0):

> > When I put an odd number I get output n-1 where n is a odd number but when i put y= even number I get output 0.I am not able to understand this please help.

With binary storage the lowest bit is always 1 for odd numbers, but since you are ANDing, you are in effect simply returning the original value-1 always (because no bits have shifted).  In the case of even numbers not all of the will be 0:  8 will:  1000 & 0111 = 0.   6 will not: 0110 & 0101 => 0100 = 4.

> > My second question is that when i print y>>2 that is 6>>2 I get ouput 1.Please explain me >>this also. I know these are bitwise operations but my concept is not clear.Thanks

It like dividing by 2 twice.  so 6->3->1.5  But the fraction part is truncated, so you are left with 1.  In binary, this would be 0110 -> 0011 -> 001.1  = 1.5 (decimal) but with truncation = 0001.